# Opera as a default web browser on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, opera

Mac OS X uses Safari as it's default browser.

Firefox has a preference option to be set up as a default browser. Does a similar mechanism exists for Opera?

If not, where is this configuration stored by OS X to change it by hand? I assume somewhere in ~/Library/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default place to change the default browser in OS X is in the Safari Prefs.

[image]

Comment: I like how people are using screenshots to demonstrate. Good idea!

Comment: beaten by half a minute! ah well.. :-)